# The IDLE is telling me that the continue function is out of loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

When trying to run my program I get the error that the continue function is out of the loop.

As I have checked my syntax I don't know what is the problem, and when trying to indent I get an error for indenting too much.

```
while True:
    print('What is your username')
    name = input()
    if name != 'Banana': # Username doesn't have to be equal to
        continue # If the username is correct they will pass on the next question
    print('Hello, Banana. What is the password? (It is a dog') # How would I put a real hint 
    password = input() # Input password
    if password == 'AkitadaMonsta':
        break # They don't have to start over again
    print('Access granted.') # Allowing them in
```

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Your post has been edited to make it readable, but perhaps the edit also corrected the problem. Does the above code match the indentation in your actual code?

Comment: When it prompts for your username, are you entering a quoted or an unquoted value?

Comment: I was using the default IDE that comes with Python but I fixed the problem. The print values were too indented for the editor and the last line didn't have to be indented at all.